# Added class using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding two classes using javascript on my table, the css for the classes is:

```
//using less
.fade-table {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    &:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.selected {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

what i am trying to achieve here is that, my table fades at the `opacity: 0.5` and the selected cell is applied with the `selected` class which highlights the selected cell.

The javascript being used is:

```
$("#pending_states table tr").live("click",function(){
    $("#pending_states table").css({width: "140px"});
    $("#pending_states td:nth-child(1), #pending_states th:nth-child(1)").addClass("fade-table");
    $("#pending_states td:nth-child(1), #pending_states th:nth-child(1)").css({width: "140px"});
    $("#pending_states").animate({ marginLeft: "4px"}, 200);
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

However for some reason after adding the `fade-table` class the script doesn't apply the `selected` class to the `td`. The obvious reason that i can think of is that this doesn't represent the td so o also tried `$(this).closest("td").addClass("selected");`. However this doesn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions on how this might work?

Comment: All of your `nth-child(1)` selectors should be replaced with `:first`.

Comment: That simply selects the first row.

Comment: That code works for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/UNgbh/)

Comment: @Pointy, Sorry forgot to mention, the `fade-table` works fine, however the `selected` class doesn't

Comment: Oh sorry - let me play with that too then ... OK I [updated the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/UNgbh/1/) and it still seems to work. The `this` reference will be the `<tr>` element, not the `<td>`.  That's because the selector you used references the `<tr>` explicitly.  I think I know what you're getting at so I'll type in an answer.

Comment: @Namit True, sorry, I misinterpreted your intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply "selected" to the `<td>` that was clicked on, try:

```
 $("#pending_states table tr").live("click",function(e){
    $("#pending_states table").css({width: "140px"});
    $("#pending_states td:nth-child(1), #pending_states th:nth-child(1)").addClass("fade-table");
    $("#pending_states td:nth-child(1), #pending_states th:nth-child(1)").css({width: "140px"});
    $("#pending_states").animate({ marginLeft: "4px"}, 200);
    ($(e.target).is('td') ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest('td')).addClass("selected");
 });
```

(or something less ugly).  The idea is to use the event parameter to find the actual target of the click.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to change the target of the event rather than trying to find the closest td/th?

Comment: @circusbred Yes if this is all that's going on; even if not, the `<tr>` is pretty easy to get to, and since it's done with delegation it doesn't make much difference really.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting opacity on the wrong element.  `fade-table` is applied to the cell, but selected is applied to the row, so the cell will still be set at 50% opacity.

http://jsfiddle.net/UNgbh/2/